# How to get the Column Data of an Excel Sheet by Column header name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have an Excel sheet like this.

| Name | Email | Phone Number | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | abc | 001 | USA |
| B | abf | 002 | CAN |
| C | abe | 003 | CHI |
| D | abd | 004 | UK |

And a Dropdown list on an HTML page like this

- Name
- Email
- Address

What I want when a user clicks on any of the items in the list box e.g on the `Name` Only The values from the name column should be fetched and converted into the JSON object.

I have tried this solution but I don't know how to specify the column name in the code.

```
  var selectedFile;
        document
            .getElementById("fileUpload")
            .addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
            });
        document
            .getElementById("uploadExcel")
            .addEventListener("click", function () {
                if (selectedFile) {
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                        var data = event.target.result;

                        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                            type: "binary"
                        });
                        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
                            let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(
                                workbook.Sheets[sheet]
                            );

                            let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(rowObject);
                            document.getElementById("jsonData").innerHTML = jsonObject;
                            console.log(jsonObject);
                        });
                    };
                    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
                }
            });
```

I am a newbie to javascript, so any help would be appreciated. Please only mention the javascript solutions.
Thanks in advance.